# flutter: geolocator isnt working, Make sure at least ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION are defined in the manifest

Tags: android, flutter, location

I am trying to use geolocator and i added both

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

to my AndroidManifest under main package and i get this error:E/flutter (21706): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: No location permissions are defined in the manifest. Make sure at least ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION are defined in the manifest.
my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="leora3y.co.el_joker">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="el_joker"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below steps to resolve your issue .

```
1. Sync gradle from android studio (must required step) 
2. flutter clean
3. flutter pub get
4. flutter run
```

Answer (score 3):

FIRST EDIT YOUR ANDROID MANIFEST FILE AND ADD THESE

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Then request for the user's location permission because without requesting for his permission you won't be able to fetch it.

LocationPermission permission;
permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();

Add the above two lines in your async function you created
and at last run these commands in your terminal

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. flutter run

You are good to go now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to re-run the app when you add permissions or anything to the AndroidManifest .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to request the permission

```
 LocationPermission permission;
permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
```

Answer (score 0):

some times this happen just because of internet permission missing.You must have defined all these permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```