# Flutter location permission issues in android manifest file

Tags: flutter, dart, android-manifest, manifest, flutter-android

my Flutter code :

```
 onPressed: () async {
                  Geolocator
                      .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best, forceAndroidLocationManager: true)
                      .then((Position position) {
                    setState(() {
                      _currentPosition = position;
                      print ( "LAT: ${_currentPosition.latitude}, LNG: ${_currentPosition.longitude}");
                    });
                  }).catchError((e) {
                    print(e);
                  });
                },
```

it show the following :

```
`No location permissions are defined in the manifest. Make sure at least CCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION are defined in the manifest.
```

even thought I have added the permission in the manifest

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.agent">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <application
        android:label="agent"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and I have the following errors that I cannot fix :
[image]

Attribute android:icon is not allowed here
Unresolved class 'MainActivity'

Comment: Uninstall your app and run flutter clean command then run

Comment: same issue don't work

Comment: Did you open a folder of the Flutter project? How about opening the Android project folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best needs both

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, try `gradle sync`. As is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752257/flutter-geolocator-isnt-working-make-sure-at-least-access-fine-location-or-acc/65761663#65761663):

> 1. Sync gradle from android studio (must required step)
> 2. flutter clean
> 3. flutter pub get
> 4. flutter run

Secondly, if it still does not work, it may be caused by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083913/android-gps-requires-access-fine-location-error-even-though-my-manifest-file). To solve this, please use [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package to request the [Permission.location](https://pub.dev/documentation/permission_handler_platform_interface/latest/permission_handler_platform_interface/Permission/location-constant.html) or other similar permissions, before you actually use your geo plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I add some information below to the [@OmarMohamoud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69361528/9192954).

You can check the [geolocator package docs](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator#usage). It talks about main 2 points

- For **AndroidX** version of Android Support Libraries, add 2 properties and check the SDK version.
- Add location **permissions**.

If you are in Android +10 and "*if you want to continue receiving updates even when your App is running in the background*" according to the docs, you have to add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Check carefully the docs.

Answer (score 1):

**Add this lines inside**

android->app->src->main->AndroidManifest.xml

android->app->src->profile->AndroidManifest.xml

android->app->src->debug->AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Recommended for Android 9 (API level 28) and lower. -->
<!-- Required for Android 10 (API level 29) and higher. -->
<service
   android:name="MyNavigationService"
   android:foregroundServiceType="location" ... >
<!-- Any inner elements would go here. -->
</service>
```

[Read this article](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions)